# Base class with abstract subclasses in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, abstract

```
public abstract class Request
{
   public class Parameters
   {
       //Threre are no members here
       //But there should be in inherited classes
   }

   public Request()
   {
       parameters = new Parameters();
   }

   public Parameters parameters;
}
```

***Two questions:***

1. How do I make it so I can add stuff to the **constructor** but the original **constructor** will still be executed?
2. How do I make it so the subclasses can add members to the *Parameters* class?

Comment: Hm ... I don't know how to word the question correctly

Comment: I'm with you on #2. Can you explain #1 a little more? Are you trying to leave the ctor closed to modification but open to extension?

Comment: If this is for JSON handling as you described below why even bother having a strongly typed Parameters object at all? Just stick all the parameters in an IDictionary. Parameters is just a data-transfer-object anyways, its not going to have any behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're doing what I think you are you would have to change your constructor slightly:

```
public Request(Parameters parameters) {
  this.Parameters = parameters;
}
```

and then you can do this:

```
public class SpecificRequest : Request {
  public class SpecificRequestParameters : Request.Parameters {
  }
  public SpecificRequest() : base(new SpecificRequestParameters()) {
    //More stuff here
  }
}
```

What's the specific problem that you're trying to address?  What you're doing here seems fairly awkward and overly complicated.

Comment: Implementing JSON communication. I wish this could be done using arrays. Grrrrr .... I hate it - I have about 20 classes for each request and 20 more for corresponding responses :(

Comment: You may consider using something like JSon.Net ?

Comment: I am using JSON.NET - I am serializing JSON objects into classes

Comment: If this is JSON why even bother having a strongly typed Parameters object at all?  Just stick all the parameters in an IDictionary.  Parameters is just a data-transfer-object anyways, its not going to have any behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you embed the Parameters class inside the Request class? Instead, let Request have an instance of parameters and just declare the class somewhere else.

Answer for your question 1:
Inherit from Request and the original request constructor will always be called.

Question 2:
Subclasses cannot add members to parameter classes (except with reflection, but you dont want to walk that path). Best you can do is inherit from parameter and have the InheritedRequest use the InheritedParameter class. Note that in that case you cannot override the properties and properties. You will have to have an additional property in InheritedRequest called AdditionalParameters of type InheritedParameters.

Answer (score 1):

Constructors can be chained with the syntax

```
ctor() : this()
```

or

```
ctor() : base()
```

in there you can pass parameters along etc.

Make the Parameters field generic

```
abstract class Request<T> where T : Parameters {
  T Parameters;
}

class Specialized : Request<SpecialParameters> {
}
```

where `SpecialParameters` inherits from `Parameters`.